# C# Linq to CSV Dynamic Object runtime column name

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, .net-4.5

I'm new to using Dynamic Objects in C#.  I am reading a CSV file very similarly to the code found here: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9780321637208/csharp-4dot0-features/ch08lev1sec3

I can reference the data I need with a static name, however I can not find the correct syntax to reference using a dynamic name at run time.

For example I have:

```
var records = from r in myDynamicClass.Records select r;

foreach(dynamic rec in records)
{
     Console.WriteLine(rec.SomeColumn);
}
```

And this works fine if you know the "SomeColumn" name.  I would prefer to have a column name a a string and be able to make the same type refrence at run time.

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off just loading the data into a `DataTable`.

Comment: do you want to decide column name at runtime?

Comment: I do want to decide the column name at runtime.  The idea being a file name could be passed to the function with a column and the data could be referenced from there.

Comment: @raholling I am actually working a project here at work which is parsing CSV files...your question was a nice diversion. Maybe I will use dynamics in my current project. :-)

Comment: @OmegaMan glad that I could be of assistance to you as well :).  Good luck on your project.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since one has to create the class which inherits from `DynamicObject`, simply add an indexer to the class to achieve one's result via strings.

The following example uses the *same* properties found in the book example, *the properties which holds the individual line data that has the column names*. Below is the indexer on that class to achieve the result:

```
public class myDynamicClassDataLine : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
{ 
   string[] _lineContent; // Actual line data
   List<string> _headers; // Associated headers (properties)

   public string this[string indexer]
   {
      get 
      {
         string result = string.Empty;
         int index = _headers.IndexOf(indexer);

         if (index >= 0 && index < _lineContent.Length)
            result = _lineContent[index];

         return result;
      }

  }
}
```

Then access the data such as

```
var csv = 
@",,SomeColumn,,,
ab,cd,ef,,,";  // Ef is the "SomeColumn"

var data = new myDynamicClass(csv); // This holds multiple myDynamicClassDataLine items

Console.WriteLine (data.OfType<dynamic>().First()["SomeColumn"]); // "ef" is the output.
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use reflection. To get the names you would use:

```
List<string> columnNames = new List<string>(records.GetType().GetProperties().Select(i => i.Name));
```

You can then loop through your results and output the values for each column like so:

```
foreach(dynamic rec in records)
{
    foreach (string prop in columnNames)
         Console.Write(rec.GetType().GetProperty (prop).GetValue (rec, null));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string column = "SomeColumn";
var result = rec.GetType().GetProperty (column).GetValue (rec, null);
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Can not perform runtime binding on a null reference". rec.SomeColumn still Works.

Comment: Yes.  If I use the syntax "rec.SomeColumn" I get data, but if I try and used the suggested code with a string "SomeColumn" I get the stated error.

Comment: Instead of using var, try using dynamic instead - I think var might be trying to typecast it and it isn't known at compile time.